# "You must pass in a non null View" when trying to get Facebook profile picture to ImageView

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Facebook auth and trying to fetch profile picture to menu ImageView tried everything but it says same thing.

This is the Code in HomeScreen.java that has menu in it, And my Login is in MainScreen.java if you need other codes please let me know.

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private CircleImageView mProfile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.MyNavTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);


    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.opendrawer, R.string.closedrawer);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    /**-------------------Facebook Profile Picture-----------------------*/
   mProfile = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivProfile);
   int dimensionPixelSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(com.facebook.R.dimen.com_facebook_profilepictureview_preset_size_large);
   Uri profilePictureUri= Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(dimensionPixelSize , dimensionPixelSize);
   Glide.with(this).load(profilePictureUri)
           .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
           .into(mProfile);

}
```

ImageView I'm trying to put it in

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Error:

```
08-02 11:04:46.791 22863-22863/com.shopfolio.shopfolio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.shopfolio.shopfolio, PID: 22863
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shopfolio.shopfolio/com.shopfolio.shopfolio.HomeScreen}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View
                                                                             at com.bumptech.glide.GenericRequestBuilder.into(GenericRequestBuilder.java:678)
                                                                             at com.bumptech.glide.DrawableRequestBuilder.into(DrawableRequestBuilder.java:448)
                                                                             at com.shopfolio.shopfolio.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:56)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
08-02 11:04:46.791 22863-22863/com.shopfolio.shopfolio E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shopfolio.shopfolio/com.shopfolio.shopfolio.HomeScreen}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View
                                                                                at com.bumptech.glide.GenericRequestBuilder.into(GenericRequestBuilder.java:678)
                                                                                at com.bumptech.glide.DrawableRequestBuilder.into(DrawableRequestBuilder.java:448)
                                                                                at com.shopfolio.shopfolio.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:56)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Sorry if it's not clear enough

Comment: `mProfile` is null... are you sure that the xml you posted is included in your activity's layout?

Comment: Ohh yes i declared it, forgot to add the code
    "private CircleImageView mProfile;" It's right, right? :D

Comment: Can you post more code: the onCreate method and the private mProfile?

Comment: I edited it :D I thought more codes would be annoying to see, sorry. Btw login form is in different java file in same package